# Plot mixed effect model results by group in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels, mixed-models

I'm using a Mixed effect model with statsmodel in python and I cannot find a way to plot the results by group level. My goal is to get to this kind of plot:

[image]

which is [possible in R](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-04-11/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/sjplmer.html).

For reference, in my dataframe `df` I have three columns = `metric`, `experiment_name`, `country`.

This is the code I'm using

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

formula = "metric ~ experiment_name"

md = smf.mixedlm(formula, df, groups=df["country"])
mdf = md.fit()
print(mdf.summary())
```

The main problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the group level results. I have googled quite a lot with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to get the results at group level, at least for the random effects.

```
mdf.random_effects
```

and to plot it a [lollipop plot with matplotlib](https://fcpython.com/visualisation/lollipop-charts-in-matplotlib) after converting the data to a dataframe and transposing.